# Responsive parallax effect missing arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jQuery function that doesn't work:

> Console : ReferenceError: $ is not defined

This is the function and I don't know what's wrong with it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
        TweenLite.to($("body"), .5, {
            css: {
                backgroundPosition: "" + parseInt(event.pageX / 8) + "px " + parseInt(event.pageY / '12') + "px, " + parseInt(event.pageX / '15') + "px " + parseInt(event.pageY / '15') + "px, " + parseInt(event.pageX / '30') + "px " + parseInt(event.pageY / '30') + "px","background-position": parseInt(event.pageX / 8) + "px " + parseInt(event.pageY / 12) + "px, " + parseInt(event.pageX / 15) + "px " + parseInt(event.pageY / 15) + "px, " + parseInt(event.pageX / 30) + "px " + parseInt(event.pageY / 30) + "px"
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: That error means you have not included jquery.js in your page correctly. Either you're missing the `<script>` reference, the path to it is incorrect, or you're running the above code before jQuery has loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I did not pay attention that I've referenced a folder with a typing error... I feel silly